# how to past list to template

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I am trying to pass this eligable list to my template so that I can display it in my website but when I run the website it says that local variable 'eligable' referenced before assignment. I dont understand because this is the only time I used the word eligable in my code.

code:

```
def specificDate(response):
    empName = employeeName.objects.all
    if 'checkEmployee' in response.POST:
            n = response.POST.get("nameEmployee")
            specDate = response.POST.get("date")
            if employeeName.objects.filter(employee=n).exists() and Name.objects.filter(date=specDate).exists():
                emp = employeeName.objects.get(employee=n)
                t = Name.objects.get(name=emp, date=specDate)
                overT = Name.objects.filter(name=emp, overtime=True)
                eligable = []
                for item in overT:
                    eligable.append(item.date)
                    print('Hello')
                checkIn = t.timeIn.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                checkOut = t.timeOut.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                datee = datetime.strptime(specDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
                print("Here:: ",t.date)
                print("Month:: ",datee.month)
                messages.info(response, checkIn + ' - ' + checkOut)
                return redirect('/specificDate')
            else:
                messages.info(response, 'Name does not exist')
    else: 
        pass
    return render(response, "main/specificDate.html",  context={"empName":empName, "eligable":eligable})
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full error stack trace?

Comment: Have you considered what happens when the `else` branch is hit? Hint: `eligable` does not exist

Comment: its okay edusanketdk has gave the answer already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def specificDate(response):
    empName = employeeName.objects.all
    eligable = []
    if 'checkEmployee' in response.POST:
            n = response.POST.get("nameEmployee")
            specDate = response.POST.get("date")
            if employeeName.objects.filter(employee=n).exists() and Name.objects.filter(date=specDate).exists():
                emp = employeeName.objects.get(employee=n)
                t = Name.objects.get(name=emp, date=specDate)
                overT = Name.objects.filter(name=emp, overtime=True)
                eligable = []
                for item in overT:
                    eligable.append(item.date)
                    print('Hello')
                checkIn = t.timeIn.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                checkOut = t.timeOut.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                datee = datetime.strptime(specDate,'%Y-%m-%d')
                print("Here:: ",t.date)
                print("Month:: ",datee.month)
                messages.info(response, checkIn + ' - ' + checkOut)
                return redirect('/specificDate')
            else:
                messages.info(response, 'Name does not exist')
    else: 
        pass
    return render(response, "main/specificDate.html",  context={"empName":empName, "eligable":eligable})
```

The error was correct to be there, because in cases where your control would not inside the if block, `eligable` list won't get intialized , so after encountering the last statement, it would raise the error.

The fix was to pre-initialize the list beforehand.

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers. Explain what you changed, and why you changed it.

Comment: You do not have `checkEmployee` field in your request dict so that `if` statement goes into `else`. There's not any `eligable` variable declaration. The last line then breaks.

Comment: Just added, check it out. I hit enter by mistake so it remained incomplete. :)